# Git post-receive checkout to website not purging folder

Tags: git

I have my current workflow setup with a git repo on my web server with a post-receive hook checking out my branches `master` and `staging` to their respective folders, `master` being my live site and `staging` my staging one.

All is well and good until I rename a file, if I changed a folder `js` to `javascript` for example, when the hook checks out my branches, it will create the folder `javascript` but keep the folder `js` and it's contents from previous commits. I'm sure git has detected the files have been renamed as when I check out the branch locally the files are gone.

This is my post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/mysite/live git checkout -f master
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/mysite/staging git checkout -f staging
```

Comment: Are you using "-f" for forceful checkout ?

Comment: yes, only as per this tutorial: http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto could this be the source of my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current post-recieve hook now looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/mysite/live git clean -df
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/mysite/live git checkout -f master
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/mysite/staging git clean -df
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/mysite/staging git checkout -f staging
```

This removes all files nolonger tracked by git, and does so recursively. If I rename a file or folder it will be 'purged' on the next push to the server. If this is wrong or there is a better way to do it I may accept an alternative answer but for now this was the solution my question.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using **-f** to checkout the branch **forcefully**, the changes might not have committed properly. Please try `git commit` first, so that it will commit the changes properly and then try to checkout the branch.

I think this approach may work

Comment: so my hook should commit, then checkout each branch? but from my local copy of the repo i am already commiting then pushing the new commits?

Comment: Yes It should commit, otherwise the changes will not be pushed to the branch and you may end up with in-consistent results. So make sure that your hook should always commit the changes before switching the new branch